# How to iterate through nested array of JSON in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a data in json format getting from PHP script the data is coming in following format as follows:

```
[{
"type":"checkbox",
"grid-name":"Sports",
"values":["Cricket","Football"],
 "input":[{"Cricket":2},{"Football":1}]
},
{"type":"checkbox",
"grid-name":"Hobbies",
"values":["Playing Chess","Swimming"],
"input":[{"Playing Chess":1},{"Swimming":2}]
},
{"type":"radiobutton",
"grid-name":"Gender",
 "values":["Male","Female"],
"input":[{"Male":3},{"Female":0}]
},
{"type":"radiobutton",
"grid-name":"Citizen",
"values":["Indian","NRI"],
"input":[{"Indian":3},{"NRI":0}]
},
{"type":"number",
"grid-name":"Age",
"input":["24","23","23"]
},
 {"type":"select",
"grid-name":"City",
"values":["Satara","New york","Korea"],
"input":[{"Satara":1},{"New york":1},{"Korea":1}]
}]
```

i want to capture the values & input array. How to access through nested array?

Comment: If you request the das with jQuery, and the server sends the correct information, then the JSON formatted String will be automatically parsed into a JavaScript Object. The Resulting array can be iterated using a normal `for` loop, or the `forEach` function provided by an Array.

Comment: Where do you need to capture it? There are many functions like `each()`/`map()` available.

Comment: probably i need to capture value & input data where value data is simple an array at the place of value whereas input is array inside array at the place of value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$.each(yourObject, function( index, value ) {
    console.log(value.values);
    console.log(value.input);
});
```

Native js (**but better don't use it, accordingly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)**):

```
for (index in yourObject) {
    console.log(yourObject[index].values);
    console.log(yourObject[index].input);
}
```

Native js, another example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < yourObject.length; i++) {
    console.log(yourObject[i].values);
    console.log(yourObject[i].input);
}
```

Comment: The structure shown by the OP is an Array, and the OP also asks about Array, so you should not suggest a `for-in` loop or at least make clear that this should only be used for Objects ([Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504))

Comment: @t.niese agreed.. `Foreach` preffered.

Comment: inside your each you should write one more... `$.each(yourObject, function( index, value ) {
    $.each(value.input, function( i, v ) {
    /* Here code ... */
    });
});`

Comment: Added native js another example. I know, that it isn't actual already, but just for example...

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `$.each`. This will allow you to loop through object-arrays.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

If you're also asking how to capture the values and you have the raw text, you're also looking for `$.parseJSON`

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/